# Should I be using custom converters for Retrofit?

Tags: android, rest, retrofit2

I've just started learning about Retrofit 2. I need to consume a RESTful API for an existing Android app. Essentially, the data model for the Android app already exists. I have a REST service which doesn't directly translate to the model classes / properties used by the app (i.e. internally the class properties do not comply with the kind of naming required by Retrofit to work automatically).

For example, given a `Car` object, the API may return `make`, `model` and `color`. The app's internal model has an existing `Vehicle` class instead, and property names do not directly map. Moreover, there are certain properties that must be initialized in a particular order.

I know this qualifies for a Custom Converter but would you suggest I instead look into a custom Gson Deserializer? Would that be a better / easier choice instead?

Any guidance would be appreciated as I've just started reading up on Retrofit. I like the fact that I don't have to write all the boilerplate code, yet I feel like I'm unable to utilize its full potential given I need to 'map' all the objects and their properties manually.

Comment: I'd have a look at the Jackson Converter.  Jackson offers a range of annotations like : `@JsonPropertyOrder` - ordering properties , `@JsonProperty("my_property")` - json property to POJO mapping and `@JsonIgnoreProperties` - to dismiss properties you don't want to use and many more - I only started using Jackson yesterday, and have successfully used all these annotations and work as desired.  A custom converter just does away with some boiler plate for a particular library, be it Gson, Jackson etc..

Comment: @MarkKeen thanks! Although near the end did you mean to describe what a custom converter does, while your suggestion to use Jackson remains? Thanks for both as I now see what the difference is between a retrofit converter and a deserializer. All tutorials I read suggested I use gson. So perhaps I now need to learn about Jackson and use that to do all my mappings / orderings and pre-processing.

Comment: With retrofit you can use a converter or not - if you don't you can still easily pass the API response to Gson/Jackson etc, Retrofit offers convenience with a converter. I've used Gson converter with Retrofit2, I have also used Gson standalone.  I have started using Jackson, and prefer it already.  All indications I've seen are that it is significantly faster (not sure if Gson uses reflection and Jackson doesn't if I'm honest, however performance is better).

Comment: @MarkKeen It seems I could in fact use Jackson directly to parse Http requests - or do I still need to use Retrofit? Either way, any good tutorial you could point me to? The stuff on Jackson's own website is daunting and scary :)

Comment: You can use Jackson to convert directly .. Retrofit abstracts this away, under the hood it uses okhttp anyway, so you could use okhttp in conjunction with Jackson independently..

Comment: @MarkKeen thanks, I might just do that as performance is important for the task at hand, and given I'd have to write custom converters and do error checking manually, Retrofit may be unnecessary. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you need to consider:

1) Does you API response keeps the same (even with missing attributes) format

then:

1.1) you can make a custom converter or deserializer

1.2) modify&sync your internal Android model to represent the one you receive or vice versa as if your Android model differ allot it can involve lots of computation on every response

else:

2)if your API responses are in different format and it is really RESTful API then you should have information of the media type by some means in the header or in the body of the response and based on this info you can then choose the appropriate converter/deserializer.
This is more like Custom Converter that delegates to another Converter based on the actual response.

For both scenarios you can apply some kind of in-the-middle converter/mapper after you get response from Retrofit which is possibly the easiest but again it will consume CPU and memory everytime you get a response.